# Mongoose - How to aggregate contents from two collections

Tags: javascript, sql, database, mongodb, mongoose

How can I use a Mongoose aggregate operation for this?
Basically, I have two collections - 'Post' and 'Profile'.
A user oid called "user" is the common reference between them.
I want to use the ID from 'Post' to look up the "handle" element from 'Profile' and aggregate those results, so that the user's handle is included in the response.

Here is how I was able to achieve this when looking up a single post:

```
// @route   GET api/posts/:id
// @desc    Get post by id
// @access  Public
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
  Post.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(post => {
      Profile.findOne({ user: post.user })
        .then(profile => res.json({ ...post._doc, userHandle: profile.handle }));
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ "not found": err }));
});
```

However, when I tried to extend this approach (using a map operation) to the GET that returns ALL of the posts, it became unworkable.

```
// @route   GET api/posts
// @desc    Get all the posts
// @access  Public
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(posts =>
      posts.map(
        post =>
          Profile.findOne({ user: post.user })
            .then(profile => (
              {
                ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(post)),
                userHandle: profile.handle
              }))
      ))
    .then(posts => res.json(posts))
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ "none found": err }));
});
```

In other words, if I have
**POST:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d1523b98d9dd16d832a8c5e"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5d1504e29dc0bd55461adca7"
    },
    "recipeName": "Pizza",
    "ingredients": "Flour and sauch"
}
```

and **PROFILE:**

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d1505089dc0bd55461adca8"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5d1504e29dc0bd55461adca7"
    },
    "handle": "jack",
    "status": "Developer"
}
```

then what I really want is a JSON object like this (when I query a post):
(notice 'userHandle' is now present)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5d1523b98d9dd16d832a8c5e"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5d1504e29dc0bd55461adca7"
    },
    "recipeName": "Pizza",
    "ingredients": "Flour and sauch",
    "userHandle": "jack"
}
```

My GET needs to return a whole array of these posts.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.find().sort({date: -1}).then((posts) => {
  Post.populate(posts, [{
    path: 'user',
    select: {}, // projection
    model: User // User model
  }], (err, posts) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.json(posts);
  });
});
```

Read More About mongoose [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

### Edit

If you don't want to include `model` every time, you can add `ref` (collection name) in the `Schema` field, and it will automatically specify the model!

#### Example:

```
const postSchema = Schema({
  ...
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' }
});
```

Comment: this still returns "Post" with the same number of keys - user.handle is still not included

Comment: so you want to return only `post.user`?

Comment: I want 'post' with the handle from 'user'.. I will add examples up top.

Answer (score 0):

```
getUserDetails: (request, response, next) => {
        try {
            let aggrQuery = [
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "Profiles",
                        localField: "Id",//key name of common id in post collection as a reference
                        foreignField: "profileId",// key name of common id in profile collection
                        as: "userDetails"// handle element as well as other data in profile collection will be stored in userDetails
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                       //we have to carry "_id", "ingredients","recipeName","user" of post collection for the next projection,and whole user information is stored in "userDetails"
                        "_id": 1,
                        "ingredients":1,
                        "recipeName":1,
                        "user":1,
                        userDetails : { $arrayElemAt : 
                      ["$userDetails", 0]}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        //finally we prepare required data set for response,"_id", "ingredients","recipeName","user" of post collection,and only userHandle of Profiles from userDetails array(which contains all profile data)
                        "_id": "$_id",
                        "ingredients":"$ingredients",
                        "recipeName":"$recipeName",
                        "user":"$user",
                        "userDetails":{
                           "userHandle" :"$userDetails.userHandle",
                           "additionField1":"$userDetails.additionField1",
                           "additionField2":"$userDetails.additionField2",
                         }     
                    }
                }
            ]
            Post.aggregate(aggrQuery).exec((err, result) => {
                if(err){
                  response.json({
                      isError: true,
                      statuscode: 404,
                      details: null
                  })
                }
                else{
                   response.json({
                    isError: false,
                    statuscode: 200,
                    details: result
                  })
                }
            })
        }
        catch{
            response.json({
                isError: true,
                statuscode: 404,
                details: null
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: I think this is what I want, but for some reason "userDetails" just comes back as an empty array : /

Comment: I did get this to work by changing "from: "Profile"" to "from: "profiles"", but how to I get the user handle specifically instead of adding the entire Profile as "userDetails" ?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifically naming fields from Posts? I think additional fields may be added in the future, and it would be easier if there was a way to just include all of them without naming them in the projection.

Comment: As far as I know all data of targeted collection  is stored in an array after lookup.In the next step we have to pick up the necessary data from the array  for the next projection or next lookup according to logic if required.But one thing we can do is that,suppose we pickup 50 data from user Details  and push all data in an array inside project so that we can carry forward that newly created array for next operation instead of  declaring 50 data again and again.Please share your opinion about that.

Comment: I don't think I understand your suggestion.

Comment: In second projection i added something.will it work?

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I meant - I was saying that additional fields could be added to Post, not Profile.  I would like to avoid specifying this:                         "_id": 1,
                        "ingredients":1,
                        "recipeName":1,
                        "user":1,